# Using UIEdgeInsets in Xcode 6s Launch XIBs

Tags: uibutton, ios8, xcode6, launch, uiedgeinsets

Is it possible to use UIEdgeInsets in a XIB used as Launch Screen?

When I try to subclass my UIButton I get the error "Launch Screen may not use instances of MyButton".

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run code or use any custom classes in the Launch Screen xib, that is why you are getting that error.